Visual Studio Code "The window terminated unexpectedly (reason: 'crashed', code: '-2147483645')"
My Visual Studio Code crashed and I've tried everything to make it work again. I'm using windows. Yet, I'm just seeing a popup window that says "The window terminated unexpectedly (reason: 'crashed', code: '-2147483645')" over and over again.
I tried restarting my laptop, uninstalling and reinstalling VS code, deleting %APPDATA%\Code and %USERPROFILE%.vscode, clearing my cache and temporary files. None of these worked and I'm still getting the error.
code --disable-extension ms-python.vscode-pylance did not work as well.
I also tried running code --crash-reporter-directory  from the command line but no *.dmp file is produced in that folder. I get the same "The window terminated unexpectedly (reason: 'crashed', code: '-2147483645')" error when I tried to run that in the terminal.

Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

I just had the same issue and error message with VScode (I'm on Windows 10, vscode 1.95.3). I restarted my machine (Start menu -> power button -> Restart option) and that fixed the issue for me.
Mentioning in case anyone else runs into this issue, don't skip restarting just because it didn't work for the author.
